# Gparted reduce C drive from unused space only

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted, boot-partition

I have two questions

(1). The C drive has 130 GB space, 64 GB used and 66 unused. So if I resize C drive to 100 GB, the 30 GB will be removed from 66 GB only right and not from 64 GB?

(2). There are two options "Free space preceding" and "Free space following" . I entered 30720 MB in "Free space following". Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, when you resize a partition, free space is taken from the drive, so you can't resize to anything less than the amount of used space.
2. Yes, "Free space following" is generally the best option, since moving the beginning of a partition can cause problems. Without knowing what you are planning on doing with the space, though, I can't really answer for sure.